# Simulate electric fields due to surface charges in simple circuits using python

Tags: finite-element, python, electromagnetism

I want to simulate the electric fields in simple circuits using Python and only free software. My first goal is to reproduce the images given in [(1)](https://www.tu-braunschweig.de/Medien-DB/ifdn-physik/ajp000782.pdf) which are made by the commercial [ANSYS Maxwell](http://www.ansys.com/Products/Electronics/ANSYS-Maxwell) software. Where to start for such a project? Which libraries are suitable to attack this problem by solving Maxwell's equations numerically? And how to model and implement the circuit geometry?

I don't want a full solution but I am asking for a guide of how to attack this problem.

[image]

**References**

1. Müller, Rainer. "A semiquantitative treatment of surface charges in DC circuits." American Journal of Physics 80.9 (2012): 782-788.

Answer (score 4):

[ANSYS Maxwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansys#ANSYS_Maxwell) is a [Finite Element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) solver for Electromagnetism. So, I assume that you are looking for a Finite Element package that has a Python interface (or is written in Python).

There are some popular options like:

- [SfePy](http://sfepy.org/doc-devel/index.html#);
- [FEniCS](http://fenicsproject.org/); and
- [Agros2D](http://www.agros2d.org/).

The last one provides a Python interface and a (nice) graphic interface, and is based in Hermes2D (so it supports hp- refinement). I would suggest Agros2D.

Of course, there are many more programs that can be used with Python. You can just make a search for "Finite Elements Python".

Comment: Agros2D looks promising. However it crashes (on linux) every time I want to add a physical field. Does it work for you?

Comment: I just installed in my Linux Mint 17.2 and run a parallel plate capacitor without problem.

Comment: Which agros2d version did you use?

Comment: 3.2.0.20140529, but I suggest that if you have more questions we move this thread to the chat.

Comment: Yes we can move it to chat if you have a few minutes.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36653/agros2d